Update calculation values ​in Firebase RealTime Database
I created a simple database, when the user enters new data a database is created to calculate the number of posts entered by the user and it works well in the add-on, the problem is that during the deletion process the database is not updated by decreasing the value, i.e. if it was 1 and when deleting, it is supposed to become 0, for those who do not, the value remains 1
This code is in case of addition
private void Poste(){
    String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DatabaseReference countRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference("dbStatis")
            .child("Clinics")
            .child(userId);
    countRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
            Integer currentValue = mutableData.getValue(Integer.class);
            if (currentValue == null) {
                // Handle the case where the value is initially null
                currentValue = 0;
            }
            // Decrement the value
            int newValue = Math.max(0, currentValue + 1);
            mutableData.setValue(newValue);
            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }
        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError error, boolean committed,
                               DataSnapshot currentData) {
            if (error != null) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Transaction failed:", error.toException());
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Transaction committed.");
            }
        }
    });
}

i call code in  onCreate Poste(); If the addition is successful
on remove data
private void DeleteData(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete the recording           permanently?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("نعم", (dialog, which) -> {
        final DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("dbClinics");
        FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        StorageReference storageReference = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(imageUrl);
        storageReference.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                reference.child(key).removeValue();
                PosteDes();
                Toast.makeText(DetailClinic.this, "Permanently deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeClinics.class));
                AnimationOut();
                finish();
            }
        });
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("no", (dialog, which) -> {
        dialog.dismiss();

        });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();

}
private void PosteDes(){
    String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DatabaseReference countRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference("dbStatis")
            .child("Clinics")
            .child(userId);

    countRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
            Integer currentValue = mutableData.getValue(Integer.class);
            if (currentValue == null) {
                // Handle the case where the value is initially null
                currentValue = 0;
            }

            // Decrement the value
            int newValue = Math.max(0, currentValue - 1);
            mutableData.setValue(newValue);

            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError error, boolean committed,
                               DataSnapshot currentData) {
            if (error != null) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Transaction failed:", error.toException());
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Transaction committed.");
            }
        }
    });
}

I call code in onCreate PosteDes(); If the Remove is successful.

What is PosteDes()? Did you Poste()? Also, are you able to delete here reference.child(key).removeValue();?

It's hard to be certain, but the first thing I'd do is add a completion listener to reference.child(key).removeValue();.

It's for dbClinics when whene user remove clinic from dbClinic the value changed on dbStatis
